# How do I instantiate data sources in a web service in a way that is easily testable and can be handled with specific error codes up failure?

Tags: java, database, web-services, dao

So my team is designing a web service that flows like this. On application startup, we instantiate a resource. This resource calls a service that then instantiates data sources within its constructor. For example, the service looks like this.

```
public class Service {

private final DAO dao;

public Service() {
    this(new DAOImplementation());

public Service(final DAOInterface daoInterface) {
     this.daoInterface = DAOFactory.getInstance().getDAO(daoInterface.class)
}
```

This is great for testability, but if something blows up in the instantiation of the data source, the service will throw a 500 or generic error that makes it very hard to isolate what actually went wrong. So, my question is, how do I instantiate a data source in a way that is testable and can be handled with specific errors upon instantiation failure?

Comment: Reading between the lines, the no argument constructor is used in production while the other constructor, which accepts the DAO, is there only to support testing.  Get rid of the no argument constructor and enforce inversion of control, perhaps injecting the DAOFactory.  If there is any issue, the code will be centralized and isolated to the DAOFactory.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I will give this a shot.